# Do Russians smile at each other?

Tags: russia, local-customs, culture

I'm planning to go to Russia. In my culture, smiling is really common even to strangers. I've heard that Russians don't smile or laugh unless it's something funny or something that makes them happy. Will it be strange or will I insult anybody in Russia if I smile?

Comment: I'll let someone who knows more answer, but here's a link: http://www.nationaljournal.com/politics/why-russians-aren-t-smiling-at-you-in-sochi-20140207. Personally, I never knew this when I was there and it wasn't an issue. I did notice that, particularly on escalators, some people (mostly men) would never make eye contact and some (mostly women) would just stare right at you.

Comment: Of course a good reason to smile is to do some drinking. And Russians generally rate drinking as a higher priority than not smiling (-:

Comment: I am Russian and by coincidence I've asked american guy mirror question just yesterday. My personal opinion: while most of the people recommend trying to blend in with the environment when travelling I might disagree. If you used to smile in your culture, be sure not to hide it when in Russia. Actually russians are very warm and friendly people and not smiling at strangers or having a smalltalk is unfortunate USSR-luggage, when every tree was considered a foreign spy.

Comment: That's an odd question.  What do you think: someone would be offended when you smile, or they really wouldn't care.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, it's true. In general, Russians never smile without a reason.

No, you will not insult anybody in Russia if you smile. But, in some cases it can be assessed as rude or strange.

For example, if you smile at a stranger he or she might think "Why is this guy looking at me and smiling? Do I look stupid?"

Smiling when you say "Hello" is OK.

In addition: don't speak with strangers if you have no business with them. There is no culture of "small talk" in Russia. If you start to talk with a stranger about the weather or traffic jams (or whatever), Russians may think that you are a fool or a salesman.

The reason why we act like this is because we respect personal space. If you have no business with the stranger, don't bother him.

Comment: Being a Russian, I disagree with that. There are many different kinds of Russians. Some people do like to smile and have "small talk" conversations. It's not a universal rule.

Comment: I don't recall people in Russia or anywhere else in the former Soviet Union respecting personal space.

Comment: I have to add that smiling when saying "Hello" is okay, but this generally should not be an XXL size "OH, I'M SO HAPPY" smile - an M size smile is just enough.

Comment: @Karlson wow, you've travelled the whole of the former Soviet Union?

Comment: @Nobilis Most of it and have quite a bit of friends from the parts I haven't visited.  Homo Soveticus doesn't vary much.

Comment: I would say that in "big city" environment - smiles and talks from random strangers are recognized as weird in Russia (at least in Moscow), but in environments where ecnounters are less "random", they are totally OK, for example - public transport, stores, situations where this is not first time ecnounter, etc. It is definitely  "enironmental" issue, not cultural or national-psychological or something like that.

Comment: I'd say it's also generational. Young people are influenced by American and European culture. We do smile at strangers sometimes :-) Like, when we find them attractive. I've only heard the "laughing without reason..." saying from elderly people.

Comment: I agree with everything except the last paragraph about personal space. It is not exactly personal space, it's indifference, zero emotions with strangers behavior and habits. There is no much of rationale behind it, and this is the reason why most Russian don't even realize this until they see how other people behave.

Comment: Just want to say that Russians are using the smiles for the people they know - but this happens at-house in general.

Comment: `you will not insult anybody ... it can be assessed as rude`. This seems like a contradiction. What did you really mean to say?

Comment: i see a little smile in that photo @MikkaRin :)

Answer (score 59):

In defense of @MikkaRin's answer, I offer a contrast of cultural norms regarding emotional expression in Russia versus USA. This may not clearly represent differences between Russian and global norms (to whatever extent these exist), but hopefully it'll help. In psychological literature concerning culture and affect, opposite norms have been described: to some extent, people from the US expect others to express positive emotions and suppress expressions of negative emotions in polite conversation, and Russians expect others to express negative emotions and suppress strongly positive emotions. [A rather technical study by Tucker, Ozer (my graduate advisor!), Lyubomirsky, and Boehm](http://drsonja.net/wp-content/themes/drsonja/papers/TOLB2006.pdf) gives this overview:

> Claimed as a right in the Declaration of Independence, personal happiness and life satisfaction play a central role in the daily social life and intellectual discourse of the United Sates. The majority of U.S. respondents rate life satisfaction as very important (Triandis et al., 1990; Diener et al., 1995) and report thinking about their personal happiness at least once every day (Freedman, 1978). By contrast, **Russians are less likely to believe that the ideal life is worth pursuing**, compared to their U.S. peers (Lyubomirsky, 1997). **Russian social life and language are rich in resources for expressing negative affect** (Wierzbicka, 1994), and **Russians appear to be relatively more concerned with the sharing of misfortune. Indeed, the expression of life satisfaction and success is often perceived to risk inviting envy, resentment, suspicion, or the ‘‘evil eye’’** (Smith, 1990). **A historical distrust of the system, combined with hopelessness, lack of control, and suspicions that anyone who is very satisfied with life must have used ‘‘crooked’’ means, steers Russians away from expressing positive feelings to others to avoid inviting negative social comparisons** (Balatsky and Diener, 1993). [Emphasis added.]

Of course, my point is not to disagree with the comments on the accepted answer to the extent that they rightly point out individual differences. Norms don't affect everyone equally, and may even promote countercultures among those predisposed to deviate from the mainstream in general, regardless of whether the norms are good or bad. Nonetheless, norms do exist on the whole, and some evidence supports the existence of the Russian norm suggested here. Still, I would be interested in any counter-arguments, qualifications, or exceptions to the general theory that commenters would care to raise here.

<sup>**References**

- Balatsky, G., & Diener, E. (1993). Subjective well-being among Russian students. *Social Indicators Research, 28*(3), 225–243.

- Diener, E., Suh, E. M., Smith, H., & Shao, L. (1995). National differences in reported subjective well-being: Why do they occur? *Social Indicators Research, 34*(1), 7–32.

- Freedman, J. L. (1978). *Happy people: What happiness is, who has it, and why*. New York: Harcourt Brace Jovanovich.

- Lyubomirsky, S. (1997). *The meaning and expression of happiness: Comparing the United States and Russia*. In Ninth Conference of the American Psychological Society, Washington, DC.

- Smith, H. (2012). *The New Russians*. Random House LLC.

- Triandis, H. C., Bontempo, R., Leung, K., & Hui, C. H. (1990). A method for determining cultural, demographic, and personal constructs. *Journal of Cross-Cultural Psychology, 21*(3), 302–318.

- Tucker, K. L., Ozer, D. J., Lyubomirsky, S., & Boehm, J. K. (2006). Testing for measurement invariance in the satisfaction with life scale: A comparison of Russians and North Americans. *Social Indicators Research, 78*(2), 341–360. Retrieved from http://drsonja.net/wp-content/themes/drsonja/papers/TOLB2006.pdf.

- Wierzbicka, A. (1994). Emotion, language, and cultural scripts. In S. Kitayama and
H.R. Markus (Eds.), *Emotion and Culture: Empirical Studies of Mutual Influences* (pp. 133–196). American Psychological Association: Washington, DC.</sup>

Comment: +1 for references. I imagine what would happen if the study said the same about a protected minority in US. It reads like a horoscope: it fits and as long as it says nice things; nobody will remind you that it is false. Disclaimer: I live in Russia.

Comment: I'd say it at least makes much stronger claims than the average horoscope. These are quite clear, falsifiable, and based on documented, observable differences. I don't think the message is particularly nice, though I suppose I could see other people in the US acting like this is a mark of superiority. Personally, I find the bias toward positivity and the suppression of negativity frustrating and harmful. Different audiences will take a given message in different lights inevitably, I suppose. That's why it's important to present empirically falsifiable claims rather than ambiguous predictions.

Comment: @NickStauner I'm a bit confused by your use of the word "falsifiable".  Maybe you meant "verifiable"?

Comment: Nope; [falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) is its own epistemological concept. The basic idea is that, in the inevitable absence of true, absolute proof, the best one can claim is that a theory could be proven wrong if it were wrong. That's why psychological statistics tend to be reported in terms of the probability that a study's data would occur if a [null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis) of no relationship or difference is true. Falsifying a null hypothesis like, "People in Russia and USA are the same," supports the theory that they're not

Comment: I have no experience outside of the US, I do have some experience with the poor.minority group. My observations is thats its almost the exact opposite. The psychology is this. If you don't act and feel confident and "good", even when you have nothing to fell "good" about, you'll be chewed and spit out by life's daily grind until there is nothing left, which is why you find a lot of them to be confident, boastful, "macho" etc. Its their attempt to conquer their environment. IDK any visiting Russian would be wise to contemplate the opposite perspective.

Answer (score 16):

This is actually conditional.

In your particular case it will not be strange or insulting though as MikkaRin pointed out they may think "What is this guy so happy about?".  Reason that it won't be for you is that you are an obvious foreigner in that country and you will be looked on as such and there is certain leeway that is allowed.

In Russia there is a rather famous proverb that goes: "Смех без причины признак дурачины" roughly translated "Laughing/Smiling without a reason is a sign of foolishness/stupidity".  So you could be looked at as such.

Is it going to be insulting to anyone you smile at?  No.  But depending on how you do it it might cause some concern on the person you smile at.

Answer (score 8):

I told a friend after I returned from Russia that Russian smiles are made of gold - they don't let go of one without a good reason. But when I was introduced to a new person, they would often smile as they said здравствуйте. When I bought half a dozen books on Russian for Foreigners, the cashier smiled as she asked "Are you learning Russian?"

If a Russian smiles when you start speaking Russian to them, it is probably because you have a funny accent (which I do). If you go around smiling for no good reason like some Americans do, you may be thought to be insane. Rather than smiling to signal your good intentions when interacting with a stranger, use the word пожалуйста (which can mean please or you're welcome depending on context). If you need to get someone's attention, say извините пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7):

I am from Russia, Yekaterinburg (it's almost Siberia you know). I tend to believe that people are not very friendly here mostly because of bad weather. Either it's really cold, or it's not, but still there is no sun because of lots of huge clouds. It's very difficult to be in a good mood when you see sun once a week. But when I travel to south regions of Russia I see the more smiles the better skies are. For example in Volgograd people are much more friendly  than here in Yekaterinburg. The only reasonable explanation is they have decent summer.

I am sure you will not insult anybody, if you are going to smile all the time, but it will make it obvious that you are a tourist (or someone could even think that you are mentally challenged) and it might attract some scum that will try to make easy money on you. So just beware smiling at train stations/subway/markets and when you cannot see direct sunlight because of huge clouds all over the skies, and you'll be fine. And feel free to smile when sun is there, people will understand why you are so happy and most of them will smile you back.

Comment: I really liked Yekaterinburg, and Volgograd!

Comment: Seeing the sun once a week, sounds like Vermont.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true. Smiling or laughing without a reason will make you look like a fool. And no, you will not insult anyone if you smile to a person in the street. But it will make you look strange. And I would not be happy if you start talking to me without a reason. Most of us are not so talkative as in Europe or Asia. But not because we are gloomy.

Answer (score 2):

Smiling without a good reason is not common in Russia (as in many other places like the UK, but perhaps slightly more so).

Generally, in a positive or neutral situation, an unexpected smile might seem strange, but won't cause an insult.

However, do beware of using a smile to defuse a tense situation where the other side is unhappy. In some smiling cultures, (e.g. Thailand, Laos) it's often appropriate to smile as an informal apology, in response to a complaint, or even upon seeing someone having a minor accident or problem. In other places, that could be interpreted as laughing at their misfortune or not taking them seriously, and could escalate the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Man, that's just a prejudice. We are smiling and laughing for reason and without one! We are common people and much easier to behave with than a lot of others. Here is no such an issue like "to be insulted if someone strangely look at you". Don' be afraid and have a good time!

Comment: It's really not "just prejudice", but I'm sure it doesn't apply equally everywhere in Russia...and the same is true of your claims. It's probably all true of some people somewhere in Russia. Diversity is the strongest rule in such a large population.

Answer (score 2):

I know a little about Russian culture. 
You will not be rude if you smile but you will be considered weak. Even though you can be yourself, smile and be a funny person but always consider respect to the Russians, they take this very seriously specially with foreigns. It's like an overly manly country.